# What is the simplest way to remove objects from a group inside of an Animation Nodes Node tree?

Tags: animation-nodes

I am attempting to create an animated particle that is an instance of a group that is created with nodes. I have been able to successfully add instanced objects to a group. While this is working fine, it is removing the objects from the group once the instance count has been reduced seems to be the only sticking point. I have tried unlinking every object in the group, from it that is beyond the index value of the instances, how ever i can not get it to remove all objects from the group or i can not get it to add all instances too the group. Can any one point me to a method that can add all objects and remove them all as well as simply as possible?

Answer (score 3):

There is a node called **Object Group Operations**. It can link/unlink objects from Object Groups. By using this in a loop you can link them all to the group.

There is no node to remove all objects from a group.

Comment: Thank you for the response, i am already using that node. the issue i believe is that when passing a parameter through a loop node, once the parameter exceeds 0, it can not return to 0. it will remain 1 in case of an integer and 1.something in case of a float.

Comment: @vailreth just wonder if the problem solved. (if so, please consider to choose this one as the best answer) And what parameter exactly you are talking about.